# Network Load Balancer on EKS with AWS Load Balancer Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have a EKS cluster deployed using the Cloudformation template from [AWS EKS Quick Start](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-amazon-eks/)

I have the add-in "AWS Load Balancer Controller" enabled while doing deployment, things look good[image]

Then, I tried to deploy a NLB with a Kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer, I follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html), quite straight forward

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Unfortunately, I got an kind of permission error, could you suggest a clue how to fix it?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the LB controller on your cluster is not enough, you need to [setup the necessary policy and permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) for your controller to interact with ELB.

Comment: okay, I thought the AWS EKS Quickstart has already provision all kind of necessary stuff, thanks. By the way, I cannot delete the service now (might be because of the error, it is in pending forever), how I can force it to be deleted (sample-service   LoadBalancer   172.20.91.141   <pending>     80:31816/TCP   5h30m)

Comment: Don't force delete a LB service or it may become an orphan object. Do mark the answer as it guided you to the correct path.